# Is my CPU compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, amd-ryzen

Would an AMD Ryzen 7 2700 3.2ghz CPU be compatible with an MSI B350 Tomahawk motherboard with windows 10 home ?

Answer (score 1):

> Would an AMD Ryzen 7 2700 3.2ghz CPU be compatible with an MSI B350
>   Tomahawk motherboard?

Yes, **provided** you have already upgraded the firmware on your motherboard, to 7A34v1G.  However, I suggest you upgrade to 7A34v1H, which is the current version of the firmware.

Source: [MSI B350 Tomahawk](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B350-TOMAHAWK#down-bios)

[image]

> Would an AMD Ryzen 7 2700 3.2ghz CPU with Windows 10 Home.

Yes